# ForeignObject are ignored in a use tag by Webkit

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, svg, webkit

ForeignObject seams to be ignored by Webkit when using inside a `<use>` tag.

Code:

```
<body>
    <svg id="my-svg" width="140" height="70" style="width: 140px; height: 70px;">
        <g x="10" y="10" width="80" height="60">
            <svg x="10" y="10" width="80" height="60">
                <rect width="80" height="70" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
            </svg>
        </g>
        <g x="55" y="35" width="85" height="17">
            <foreignObject width="85" height="17" x="55" y="35">
                <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="margin: 0;">Lorem</p>
            </foreignObject>
        </g>
    </svg>

    <svg pointer-events="none" x="15" y="10" width="141" height="71">
        <use xlink:href="#my-svg"></use>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Result in Chrome/Safari/Opera:
[image]

Result in Firefox
[image]

Is my code correct? Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

It seams to be a bug in Webkit and it won't be fixed for now...

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91515